# How does November relate to death?

Tags: analysis, the-november-man

in *The November Man* when Devereaux meets with Hanley to tell him where he (or Mason who Hanley sends) can find Filipova in exchange for his daughter's safety, Hanley says

> You know what we used to call you, Peter? The November Man. 'Cause after you passed through, nothing lived. You are one bleak motherfucker, my friend.

Now i get the reason for the nickname beyond being just a title drop because almost everyone Devereaux did encounter did end up dying, but what i don't get is why November? December would make more sense since after December passes though that's the end of the year and some depictions of the new year shows the year just passed as an old man

[image: New Year]

and this you could consider the year just pass "dying" after December.

So how is it that November is used in this context of everyone passing it dying? i see no connection between November or it's number 11 and death

Comment: I need to do more research, but the character's surname took me to a variant, which took me to a history of family with said surname, whose origins took me to the center of Jewish learning--so I'm wondering if it relates Hanukkah at all, which whose celebration starts at the end of November????? Also "Peter" as Biblical figure might be significant.

Comment: That line only works for people who experience a cold winter. If you live in the south you must think that line makes no sense at all.

Comment: Where I grew up, things started dying around the beginning of November, and by December were already dead. So when the quote says, "after you passed through, nothing lived." that sounds more like November than December when everything is already dead.

Comment: As others have said, it's just because typically winter starts getting really cold in November and trees/plants start dying.